# how to require a javascript file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and have a javascript file in app/assets/javascripts `vex.combined.js` and how can I require it within application.js?

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .

var vex = require('vex.combined');
```

returns an error in browser console: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Update:

By using `//= require vex.combined`

How can I transform `vex.registerPlugin(require('vex-dialog'));` ?

It returns

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, you don't need to use this `var vex = require('vex.combined');`

[**Rails Asset Pipeline:**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write these assets in other languages such as CoffeeScript, Sass, and ERB.

**For example**

When we include a file using `application.js` like `//= require select2` then we access to this all methods like after requiring this then we just called the method like `select2();`

```
$("#ID").select2();
```

when we remove this `//= require select2` from `application.js` then it will show

> ReferenceError: select2 is not a function

Try the following.

For the most common usage of vex, you'll want to include vex, vex-dialog, the vex CSS file, and a theme file.

```
//= require vex.combined
```

make sure directory is ok, then try to run basic alert like

```
vex.dialog.alert('Thanks for checking out vex!')
```

that's actually ok.

```
var vex = require('vex-js')
vex.registerPlugin(require('vex-dialog'))
```

Above two lines code for browserify/webpack setup which you are trying.